# How do I find the efficiency of a transformer?

Tags: transformer, efficiency

I am very new to transformers.  I want to find the efficiency of transformer at an existing stage.

How do I find the practical efficiency of a transformer? What are the formulae and parameters we should know to find the efficiency?

After finding the existing efficiency, I want find the effect of heat loss in transformer design so that I can give space to ventilation in my design.

Comment: What stage is *existing stage*? Design idea, working though the ashes of a component failure, somewhere in between? *ventilation* reads *power transformer*/mains/grid frequency: How many digits in watts?

Comment: I have one existing transformer. But i don't know which parameters to go through to answer your query. If you suggest me the parameters then i can tell you something

Comment: `which parameters` \$P_{out}\$ (VA or W) and \$f_{nom}\$ (Hz) would be a start.

Comment: Its written high voltage strength: I.P 2.5Kv, O:P 2.5KV , I:O 5KV,  nominal voltage 550v to 500v and turn ratio is 8:9 and in this all i don't know what is high voltage strength

Comment: Although possible, it’s unlikely you have a 2.5 kV:2.5 kV transformer. Those look more like primary to case/core and primary to secondary hipot test values. Efficiency is always n=Pout/Pin.

Comment: Most well designed transformers are in the 95%-98% range of efficiency.

Comment: @winny if that's the case then my transformer will be of 100% efficiency. I don't think that's possible in real world.

Comment: Can anyone tell me formula of  the efficiency with all losses included

Comment: @winny what is I:O 5KV? In that values. And with all those values I mentioned can we get efficiency of the transformer?

Comment: Input to output hi-pot test voltage. You can’t. If the manufacturer does not provide it, you need to measure it.

Comment: @winny have electrical rating 550V to 500V, 25KW. I guess with that also its not possible to calculate its efficiency. and other some test values on dielectric strength.

Comment: Correct. If you don’t have access to a known load or current clamps, you could estimate it by measuring the winding resistance of both primary and secondary.

Comment: @winny, In data sheet resistance is not mentioned. but they gave us material information with its dimensions of core , bobbin, primary to secondar insulation , tape and tubing. They have skipped the resistance part. And I do not have multimeter to measure resistance manually of windings by my own. Is there any way to find that out you think?

Comment: Either assume 95 % efficiency and move on or get the equipment needed to measure it.

Comment: @Amol - If you looking for a formula, it would just be Pout/Pin.  Note the Pout is reduced from Pin by 1) resistive losses and 2) eddy current losses.  I'm not a transformer design expert, so there may be other losses involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the losses you can compute the efficiency for a given load factor using:
$$\eta=\frac{P{out}}{P{in}}=\frac{S\ b\ PF}{S\ b\ PF+P_{k}\ b^2+P_{0}}$$
where \$\eta\$ is the efficiency [p.u.], \$S\$ is the rated power of the transformer [VA], \$b\$ is the load factor [p.u.], \$PF\$ is the power factor, \$P_{k}\$ is the load losses [W] and \$P_{0}\$ is the no-load losses [W].

Regarding the heating, without further detailed information about the design, is not possible to make too many calculations. One can rely on the convection coefficients (from natural to forced convection) to estimate the change in the temperature. But some aspects as the surface available for convection will strongly influence the results.